# MySQL query containing IF or CASE to select inactive users

Tags: mysql

I have to create a query to MySQL database which is too complicated for me to understand how to create it ... I need to select all users that was inactive for 1 year or more. User is active, if he added at least 1 comment or 1 request or 1 message during the last year.
It should be something like:

SELECT * FROM Users WHERE RegDate < NOW()-INTERVAL 1 YEAR

and... if he has any Comments:
AND Comment.CommentDate < NOW()-INTERVAL 1 YEAR

and... if he has any requests:
AND Requests.RequestDate < NOW()-INTERVAL 1 YEAR

and... if he has any messages:
AND Messages.MessageDate < NOW()-INTERVAL 1 YEAR

But the query will not work in this way because in case the user doesn't has any Messages, but has very old Requests or Comments, the query will not select him. I think, I need to add somehow IF() or CASE() in my query, but I don't know how.

Sample: 4 tables: Users, Comments, Messages, Requests

Should be selected:

1. UserA, registered 10.05.2017, no messages, no requests, 2 comments, the last one - 15.05.2017
2. UserC, registerd 15.08.2017, several requests, the last one - 16.08.2017, several comments the last one - on 17.08.2017, some messages, the last one - 18.08.2017

Should not be selected:

3. UserD, registered at 10.04.2017, he has one comment from 10.11.2017 (it is not older than 1 year) and one message from 10.06.2017 (older than 1 year)

Can you help?

Thanks.

**RESULTS:**
I try to combine things from your answers, e.g.:

```
select u.Email, uf.Phone
from User u, UserFields uf
LEFT JOIN Request r ON u.UserID = r.UserID
where u.UserID=uf.UserID
and u.TimeCreated < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
and u.UserID NOT IN (select r.UserID from Request as r where u.UserID=r.UserID AND r.TimeCreated >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
LIMIT 0,100
```

This is real query, I need to merge the tables User and UserFields, and I get an error: 1054 - Unknown column u.UserID in on clause
It seems, the "ON" clause is right... but why it doesn't work?

**FINAL RESULT:**
I will use this query:

```
select u.Email, uf.FirstName, uf.LastName, uf.Phone, r.TimeCreated as ReqTime
from User u
INNER JOIN UserFields uf ON u.UserID=uf.UserID
LEFT JOIN Request r ON r.UserID=u.UserID
where u.TimeCreated < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
GROUP BY u.Email
HAVING
    (ReqTime < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR) OR ReqTime is NULL)
LIMIT 0,100
```

But will add here the Comment and Message tables. I tried with Request only and it seems to work well...

Thank to all who helped!

Comment: How are the four tables joined ?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: I don't konw how they should be joined

Comment: Share table structures with sample data

Comment: Please edit your question to include details. Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Ref: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presumed that the tables are connected in this manner:

1. user 1 --- * comment (foreign key: user_id)
2. user 1 --- * request (FK: user_id)
3. user 1 --- * messages (FK: user_id)

**EDIT**: I have completely re-worked the answer in order to avoid confusion.

Anyways, the following query should work in your case, when doing the JOIN + GROUP BY approach:

```
select 
    u.*, 
    max(c.comment_date) 'last_comment',
    max(r.request_date) 'last_request',
    max(m.message_date) 'last_message'
from user u
left join comment c on u.id = c.user_id
left join request r on u.id = r.user_id
left join message m on u.id = m.user_id
where 
    u.register_date < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
group by
    u.id
having
    (last_comment < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR OR last_comment is NULL)
    AND (last_request < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR OR last_request is NULL)
    AND (last_message < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR OR last_message is NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think this query will not work as I need. E.g. If an user has one Comment which is older than 1 year and one Request which is newer than 1 year, the query will select him, but the user is active and sould not be selected. What if I will replace OR with AND ?

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean, so I quickly edited my answer. My take is that your query would fare better with NOT EXISTS than if I started to "fix" it by other ways, such as the "joins and group by" approach along with changing the where conditions. Hope that updated query helps!

Comment: Thank you, but how can I take the data from Comments or Messages or requests? I have to show the date of last record on my result page.

Comment: you mean you need to display the data about inactive user, plus his (eventual) last message he made, last request made, or last comment he posted?

Comment: Just date-added for Last Comment, Last Request and Last Message

Comment: ok, I tested the query I added, it's not fully correct. I'll go and check and post updated solution soon

Comment: ok, fixed second query, now it should work properly, I did a quick test as well

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use following to get users as per your criteria

```
SELECT * 
FROM Users u
WHERE (u.RegDate < CURRENT_DATE() -INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Comments WHERE user_id = u.id AND CommentDate > CURRENT_DATE()-INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Requests WHERE user_id = u.id AND RequestDate > CURRENT_DATE()-INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Messages WHERE user_id = u.id AND MessageDate > CURRENT_DATE()-INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

OR via join you could write it as

```
SELECT u.id, u.name ,MAX(c.CommentDate) CommentDate ,MAX(r.RequestDate) RequestDate ,MAX(m.MessageDate) MessageDate
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN Comments c ON u.id = c.user_id
LEFT JOIN Requests r ON u.id = r.user_id
LEFT JOIN Messages m ON u.id = m.user_id
WHERE u.RegDate  < CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
GROUP BY u.id, u.name
HAVING MAX(c.CommentDate) < CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
AND MAX(r.RequestDate) < CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
AND MAX(m.MessageDate) < CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

Answer (score 1):

We can get the result using `not in` criteria also.

I tried the following query and sample data

```
select u.* from Users as u
where u.RegisterDate < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
and u.id not in (select c.id from Comments as c where c.comment_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
and u.id not in (select r.id from Requests as r where r.request_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
and u.id not in (select m.id from Messages as m where m.message_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
```

For sample data use the following query

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    RegisterDate datetime,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Comments (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    comment varchar(255),
    comment_date datetime,
    user_id int,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES Users(ID)
);
CREATE TABLE Requests (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    request varchar(255),
    request_date datetime,
    user_id int,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES Users(ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Messages (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    message varchar(255),
    message_date datetime,
    user_id int,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES Users(ID)
);

insert into Users(ID, Name, RegisterDate) values
(1, 'User A', STR_TO_DATE('10.05.2017', '%d.%m.%Y')),
(2, 'User B', STR_TO_DATE('11.05.2018', '%d.%m.%Y')),
(3, 'User C', STR_TO_DATE('15.08.2017', '%d.%m.%Y')),
(4, 'User D', STR_TO_DATE('10.04.2017', '%d.%m.%Y'))
;

insert into Comments (ID, user_id, comment_date) values
(1, 1, STR_TO_DATE('14.05.2017', '%d.%m.%Y')),
(2, 1, STR_TO_DATE('15.05.2017', '%d.%m.%Y')),
(3, 3, STR_TO_DATE('17.08.2017', '%d.%m.%Y')),
(4, 4, (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MONTH))
;
insert into Requests (ID, user_id, request_date) values
(1, 3, STR_TO_DATE('16.08.2017', '%d.%m.%Y'))
;
insert into Messages (ID, user_id, message_date) values
(1, 3, STR_TO_DATE('18.08.2017', '%d.%m.%Y')),
(2, 4, STR_TO_DATE('10.06.2017', '%d.%m.%Y'))
;
```